# Why is big Foreach loop getting slower?

Tags: memory-management, foreach, text-files

I have an application built on windows form. With this application I am reading a text file of ten thousands of lines. I process individual rows in the file and save them to the database. While the first lines are very fast when processing, the processing time increases as the process continues. Looks like there's a memory increase. I don't know what is lacking. Waiting for your suggestions.

These are the codes that I use:

```
            if (ofData.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //ofData => OpenFileDialog name
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofData.FileName, Encoding.UTF8);

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    string[] res = line.Split('#');
                    string opaqId = res[0].Trim();
                    string name = res[1].Trim();
                    string surName = res[2].Trim();

                    Student s = new Student();
                    s.opaq = opaqId;
                    s.name = name;
                    s.surname = surName;

                    studentManager.Insert(s); //EntityFramework insert database
                }
            }
            ofData.Dispose();
```

Comment: Every time the for-each loop runs, a "Student" is being added to the memory, which may explain the memory increase. What does the studentManager.Insert() method looks like?

Comment: I use EntityFramework to register to the database